# Efficient way to re-order a C++ map-based collection

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, dictionary

I have a large(ish - >100K) collection mapping a user identifier (an int) to the count of different products that they've bought (also an int.) I need to re-organise the data as efficiently as possible to find how many users have different numbers of products. So for example, how many users have 1 product, how many users have two products etc.

I have acheived this by reversing the original data from a `std::map` into a `std::multimap` (where the key and value are simply reversed.) I can then pick out the number of users having *N* products using `count(N)` (although I also uniquely stored the values in a set so I could be sure of the exact number of values I was iterating over and their order)

Code looks like this:

```
// uc is a std::map<int, int> containing the  original
// mapping of user identifier to the count of different
// products that they've bought.
std::set<int> uniqueCounts;
std::multimap<int, int> cu; // This maps count to user.

for ( map<int, int>::const_iterator it = uc.begin();
        it != uc.end();  ++it )
{
    cu.insert( std::pair<int, int>( it->second, it->first ) );
    uniqueCounts.insert( it->second );
}

// Now write this out
for ( std::set<int>::const_iterator it = uniqueCounts.begin();
        it != uniqueCounts.end();  ++it )
{
    std::cout << "==> There are "
            << cu.count( *it ) << " users that have bought "
            << *it << " products(s)" << std::endl;
}
```

I just can't help feeling that this is not the most efficient way of doing this. Anyone know of a clever method of doing this?

I'm limited in that **I can't use Boost or C++11 to do this**.

Oh, also, in case anyone is wondering, this is neither homework, nor an interview question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you know the maximum number of products that a single user could have bought, you might see better performance just using a vector to store the results of the operation.  As it is you're going to need an allocation for pretty much every entry in the original map, which likely isn't the fastest option.

It would also cut down on the lookup overhead on a map, gain the benefits of memory locality, and replace the call to count on the multimap (which is not a constant time operation) with a constant time lookup of the vector.

So you could do something like this:

```
std::vector< int > uniqueCounts( MAX_PRODUCTS_PER_USER );

for ( map<int, int>::const_iterator it = uc.begin();
        it != uc.end();  ++it )
{
    uniqueCounts[ uc.second ]++;
}

// Now write this out
for ( int i = 0, std::vector< int >::const_iterator it = uniqueCounts.begin();
        it != uniqueCounts.end();  ++it, ++i )
{
    std::cout << "==> There are "
            << *it << " users that have bought "
            << i << " products(s)" << std::endl;
}
```

Even if you don't know the maximum number of products, it seems like you could just guess a maximum and adapt this code to increase the size of the vector if required.  It's sure to result in less allocations than your original example anyway.

All this is assuming that you don't actually require the user ids after you've processed this data of course (and as pointed out in the comments below, that the number of products bought for each user is a relatively small & contiguous set.  Otherwise you might be better off using a map in place of a vector - you'll still avoid calling the multimap::count function, but potentially lose some of the other benefits)

Comment: "adapt this code to increase the size of the vector if required" - which at its simplest is one line, `if (uc.second >= uniqueCounts.size()) uniqueCounts.resize(uc.second+1);`. If some counts are too big for a vector (users who have bought hundreds of millions of products?), consider a sparse container like `map` in place of the `vector`.

Comment: I guess it boils down to whether I need the intemediate data in the multimap (i.e. mapping count to user id) I'm not sure whether I do at the moment but if not, this would seem a good way to go.

Comment: @Component10 If you were really keen on having that data it'd be possible to have some sort of hybrid approach - a multimap with the userids and a vector for the counts.  Though that might be complete overkill (and possibly not even much more efficient).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "more efficient". First off, is this really a bottle neck? Sure, 100k entries is a lot, but if you only have to this every few minutes, it's ok if the algorithm takes a couple seconds.

The only area for improvement I see is memory usage. If this is a concern, you can skip the generation of the multimap and just keep a counter map around, something like this (beware, my C++ is a little rusty):

```
std::map<int, int> countFrequency; // count => how many customers with that count

for ( std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = uc.begin();
        it != uc.end();  ++it )
{
    // If it->second is not yet in countFrequency, 
    // the default constructor initializes it to 0.
    countFrequency[it->second] += 1;
}

// Now write this out
for ( std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = countFrequency.begin();
        it != countFrequency.end();  ++it )
{
    std::cout << "==> There are "
            << it->second << " users that have bought "
            << it->first << " products(s)" << std::endl;
}
```

If a user is added and buys `count` items, you can update `countFrequency` with

```
countFrequency[count] += 1;
```

If an existing user goes from `oldCount` to `newCount` items, you can update `countFrequency` with

```
countFrequency[oldCount] -= 1;
countFrequency[newCount] += 1;
```

Now, just as an aside, I recommend using an `unsigned int` for count (unless there's a legitimate reason for negative counts) and typedef'ing a `userID` type, for added readability.

Comment: Yes, it depends very much on whether the client is going to ask for the product bandings broken down by user. This is not really a bottleneck - there is a lot of DB work which is a lot slower - but just down to a feeling that it wasn't very efficient. I take your point about typedef'ing etc. The code was a simplified example which had to obfuscate clients proprietry code which is why I just went for simple ints.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, I would recommend keeping both pieces of data current all the time. In other words, I would maintain a second map which is mapping number of products bought to number of customers who bought that many products. This map contains the exact answer to your question if you maintain it. Each time a customer buys a product, let n be the number of products this customer has now bought. Subtract one from the value at key n-1. Add one to the value at key n. If the range of keys is small enough this could be an array instead of a map. Do you ever expect a single customer to buy hundreds of products?

Comment: That's a fair point. Encapsulating the two collections within an object that managed the synchronisation would be a useful way to go. The process is actually a one-off batch job and the product count functionality is a new requirement from the client which was why it wasn't designed in from scratch. Hope that puts some context behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for larks, here's a mixed approach that uses a `vector` if the data is smallish, and a `map` to cover the case where one user has bought a truly absurd number of products. I doubt you'll really need the latter in a store app, but a more general version of the problem might benefit from it.

```
typedef std::map<int, int> Map;
typedef Map::const_iterator It;

template <typename Container>
void get_counts(const Map &source, Container &dest) {
    for (It it = source.begin(); it != source.end(); ++it) {
        ++dest[it->second];
    }
}

template <typename Container>
void print_counts(Container &people, int max_count) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= max_count; ++i) {
        if contains(people, i) {
            std::cout << "==> There are "
                << people[i] << " users that have bought "
                << i << " products(s)" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}


// As an alternative to this overloaded contains(), you could write
// an overloaded print_counts -- after all the one above is not an 
// efficient way to iterate a sparsely-populated map. 
// Or you might prefer a template function that visits
// each entry in the container, calling a specified functor to
// will print the output, and passing it the key and value.
// This is just the smallest point of customization I thought of.
bool contains(const Map &c, int key) {
    return c.count(key);
}
bool contains(const std::vector<int, int> &c, int key) {
    // also check 0 < key < c.size() for a more general-purpose function
    return c[key]; 
}

void do_everything(const Map &uc) {
    // first get the max product count
    int max_count = 0;
    for (It it = uc.begin(); it != uc.end(); ++it) {
        max_count = max(max_count, it->second);
    }

    if (max_count > uc.size()) { // or some other threshold
        Map counts;
        get_counts(uc, counts);
        print_counts(counts, max_count);
    } else {
        std::vector<int> counts(max_count+1);
        get_counts(uc, counts);
        print_counts(counts, max_count);
    }
}
```

From here you could refactor, to create a class template `CountReOrderer`, which takes a template parameter telling it whether to use a `vector` or a `map` for the counts.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's unlikely that they'll want to go higher than a contiguous amount that could be managed in a vector (although they'd be chuffed to bits if their users bought millions of products!) Thanks also, for highlighting the issue of scalability which I'd not addressed: It would perhaps be sensible not to assume that my initial (input) map can be limitless in size, although I'll admit that I'm not going to code for it just yet!